# How can I back up my pre-installed Windows 8 before installing Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, backup

I want to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8 on my laptop (Toshiba L850/046 with pre-installed Windows 8). I want to be able to pick between the two operating systems at startup.

Also, how can I backup my Windows 8 software? If something went wrong (for example my Windows 8 / hard drive got wiped out), how would I be able to re-install Windows 8 from the back up?

P.S. I plan on installing Ubuntu with a DVD -- that means I don't have to make new partition spaces and can just click the **Install alongside Windows 8** option, right?

Comment: This question is about Ubuntu 13.03 which was an official Ubuntu flavor, when it was published. The question has one answer with an upvote. My understanding is that the question can not be closed for these reasons. If we can close this question, any question older than five years about a EoSS version should be closed.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron the close votes are because the question is about Windows, not because Ubuntu 13.04 is too old. Personally I think the question is borderline okay, with minor relevance to Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @Zanna: Are you saying that we can flag and close any question that mentions Windows 8? Are Windows 10 and 11 now off-topic also? A search for Windows on AU shows 4,485 questions and states: **Microsoft's Windows operating system(s). Questions with this tag should relate to Ubuntu to be on-topic for this site, which this question does.**

Comment: @C.S.Cameron No, what I was saying is that your first comment seemed to be based on an incorrect assumption about the close votes, and also that I personally think that there is no need to close the question. However, the question, apart from the final aside, is about how to perform a backup on Windows. There is nothing to be done in Ubuntu here. The relevance is slight, and the answer shows that the expertise is elsewhere "there  must be some sort of utility..." so I can understand why people feel the question should be closed.

Comment: @Zanna: The OP has Win 8 preinstalled and wants to install Ubuntu 13.04, (Which was on topic in 2013). Backing up Windows during this install was the second part of the OP's question. Backing up the Windows drive is a good idea before any dual boot Ubuntu install. Many people consider backing up Windows to be part of the Ubuntu install process and not a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop came with a preinstalled windows 8 there must be some sort of utility included to create backup disks. Just use that software to take a backup of your windows 8. However these backup may not keep your windows os settings in case of a re-installation.

[**Advanced**: If you can explore the hidden drives (by running `diskmgmt.msc`), you will see *.wim images in there, those are the windows deployment packages. You can save them also, but restoring them is a little bit complex method]

Second option is to use any cloning software to clone your hard disk to an external driver. But this usually requires the external drive capacity should be same as your laptop.

Installing ubuntu in preinstalled windows 8 is lot more complecated. Thanks to the secure boot requirement of preinstalled windows 8 PC. You can go through the link below to have a guide on how to proceed with instillation..

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: Is it better if I just get the Virtual Box version? (If there is an available version for Win 8), because I looked at the link you gave me and it's similar to a couple of videos on Youtube, but they say if you already have 4 partitions then don't continue. Unfortunately I do already have 4 partitions :/

Comment: Virtualbox/VMWARE won't give you same performance as native. Secondly you misunderstood the 4 partition problem.If you are using legacy BIOS then it is true that you can't have more than 4 primary partition but you can put three of your primary partition into a single logical partition. If you are in UEFI (UEFI is default for preinstalled win 8 laptop) then there is no bar.